# SFMC Find and Replace via SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation, sql

I have a data extension where values are imported via an Import Activity. One of those values is a URL ending in .biz. I'm trying to write a query that finds all instances of .biz with .com but encounter an error saying:

"An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only SELECT queries are valid. Select must be the first word of the query."

Here's what I wrote:

```
UPDATE [DataExtension_A]
SET LinkURL = REPLACE(LinkURL, 
'www.url.biz', 'www.url.com')
```

Is there some other way to find and replaces values in a data extension or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a substring to resolve my issue:

```
Set @url_step_1 = Substring(AttributeValue("UniqueURL"),22)
Set @url_step_2 = Concat("/", @url_step_1)
Set @url_final = concat('www.XXXXXXXXXXXX.XX/XXX',@url_step_2)
```

Then, anytime I need to link to a page that utilizes the custom URL, I use the following as the destination URL

```
%%=RedirectTo(@url_final)=%%
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use UPDATE keywords in Marketing Cloud query activity, to update rows, your data extension must have a primary key column, and you need to use **select** query to include the Primary key column, and set query update type to "Update".

For example, if the PK column in your data extension is called **ID**, query should be like below

```
select ID, REPLACE(LinkURL, 'www.url.biz', 'www.url.com') as 'LinkURL'
from [DataExtension_A]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you answer is best answered by the documentation provided by Marketing Cloud: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5

Also a previous question sheds more light onto the situation:
[Insert/ Update new rows from one data extension to another via query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199066/insert-update-new-rows-from-one-data-extension-to-another-via-query/199069#199069)